# Latest JQTouch release - does it support drag and drop based on touch?

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, jqtouch

I use JQuery's drag and drop on my website. This does not work with touch events on mobile. It is not clear from current JQTouch documentation if it has support for drag and drop based on touch events. Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

jqTouch can augment jQuery-UI's draggable() method so it works on mobile devices, apparently...

[How can I make a jQuery UI 'draggable()' div draggable for touchscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026915/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-ui-draggable-div-draggable-for-touchscreen)

Answer (score 0):

[This library](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/) might help in the meantime.

Would be nice if the added native support for touch-screen drag events to jQuery.