# Is there a javascript drag&drop that works on iPad and PC

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, ios, jquery-ui

I am looking for a javascript plugin that supports drag and drop for both touch and mouse enabled devices (IOS, Andriod) (PC, Mac).

Example for touch:
http://www.midemos.com/demos/iphone/touch/?/iphone/touch/

Example for mouse:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Is there a plugin that supports drag drop across touch and mouse based devices?

I understand touch devices uses different events, but I dont see a reason why a plugin can't support both interfaces.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026915/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-ui-draggable-div-draggable-for-touchscreen) may be helpful.

Comment: The question you linked to addresses dragging, but what about dropping?