# Drag and drop div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few classes in my web page which i would the users to drag and place it where ever they want in the page.

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #drag{ width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; background:red; margin-bottom:10px;}
  #drag1{ width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; background:blue; margin-bottom:10px;}
  #drag2{ width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; background:green; margin-bottom:10px;}
  #drag3{ width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; background:yellow; margin-bottom:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="drag">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

<div id="drag1">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

<div id="drag2">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

<div id="drag3">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

i want the simplest jquery code to implement this feature. please assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Should use the draggable plugin in jquery UI

```
$('#drag1').draggable();
```

[Jquery Example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

For more information follow below link

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343385/change-position-of-divs-with-jquery-drag-an-drop)

**Or :**

[Draggable Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/zeXuM/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the draggable plugin in jquery UI

```
$('#drag1').draggable();
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree, you could use jqueryUI's `draggable`.

For your html example, you can do it this way:

> $("body > div").draggable();

You can also add a class to all draggable divs, say "draggable-container". And use:

> $(".draggable-container").draggable();

Answer (score 1):

Okay I will guide you step by step :

- You need to have two external files in your head part.
- The first one being jquery and the second one is jquery ui
- You can select any div and add the draggable option to it like this `$("#drag").draggable();`
- See for errors like `c.browser is not defined` and `c.curPos is not defined` in the firebug window.
- These errors may arise due to jquery version you are using, as c.browser was removed in jquery 1.9.
- Your final draggable code should look like this in a fiddle.

  http://jsfiddle.net/LHELM/

Answer (score 1):

Here the full code of jquery drag and drop

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>

        $(document).on("ready", function(){
        var c = 5;
        $( "#drag, #drag1, #drag2, #drag3" ).draggable({revert: true});
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
                accept      : '#drag, #drag1, #drag2, #drag3',
                activeClass : 'drag-active',
                hoverClass  : 'drop-hover',
           drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var source = ui.draggable.clone();
            source.removeAttr( "style" );
            var style = {
                position: "absolute",
                top: c,
                left: c
            }
            source.css( style  );
            $("#droppable").append(source);
            c += 10;
          }
        });

      });
      </script>

    <style>
      #drag{ width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; background:red; margin-bottom:10px;}
      #drag1{ width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; background:blue; margin-bottom:10px;}
      #drag2{ width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; background:green; margin-bottom:10px;}
      #drag3{ width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; background:yellow; margin-bottom:10px;}
      #droppable{ width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid black;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;}
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="drag">
      <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>

    <div id="drag1">
      <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>

    <div id="drag2">
      <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>

    <div id="drag3">
      <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>

    <div id="droppable">
    <p>drop here</p>

    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. it works. but the concern is that i want to drop the boxes anywhere in the page, not in a particular section.. is this possible?

Comment: Yeah, remove the `{revert: true}` from draggable section. The color boxes can easily move any place on the page.