# How to make Adam Shaw's FullCalendar Responsive

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have searched and searched but cant find any way to make the plugin responsive, does the plugin even have any such option? if not have any one made it responsive?

I think i can make the most part responsive using css but what about drag & drop functionality any suggestion guys?

Comment: Can you be more exact about what you mean by "responsive"? If you just mean enabling drag & drop, maybe this question will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796109/jquery-drag-and-drop-on-touch-devices-ipad-android

Comment: @Avalanche I figured out that plugin is using jQuery UI drag & drop for which i found a mobile solution some where on google but i was getting some weird animation on calendar i.e if i drag element A & on drop element B would get animated from top to bottom of the screen (tested on Android -- Samsung Duos so far). I will post an answer my self once i get it working properly.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

It has almost all feature required for a calendar including drag and drop.
You can check [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/).

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: so far i have tested on Android Samsung Duos

Comment: what that has to do with responsiveness?