# Scriptaculous draggable on iOS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

How would you setup touch events to the draggable class, so that it works on iOS (iPad's, iPhone's, etc)?  I have read [How can I make a jQuery UI 'draggable()' div draggable for touchscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026915/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-ui-draggable-div-draggable-for-touchscreen/9174684#9174684), which has lots of options for jQuery, but not sure how to apply that to Scriptaculous. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by editing dragdrop.js as mention [here](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8887/tickets/325-dragdrop-activation-in-mobile-safari-iphoneipad):

In Draggables:

```
  register: function(draggable) {
    if(this.drags.length == 0) {
      this.eventMouseUp   = this.endDrag.bindAsEventListener(this);
      this.eventMouseMove = this.updateDrag.bindAsEventListener(this);
      this.eventKeypress  = this.keyPress.bindAsEventListener(this);


      Event.observe(document, "mouseup", this.eventMouseUp);
      Event.observe(document, "mousemove", this.eventMouseMove);
      Event.observe(document, "keypress", this.eventKeypress);


      Event.observe(document, "touchstart", this.eventKeypress);
      Event.observe(document, "touchmove", this.eventMouseMove);
      Event.observe(document, "touchend", this.eventMouseUp);
    }
    this.drags.push(draggable);
  },


  unregister: function(draggable) {
    this.drags = this.drags.reject(function(d) { return d==draggable });
    if(this.drags.length == 0) {
      Event.stopObserving(document, "touchstart", this.eventKeypress);
      Event.stopObserving(document, "touchmove", this.eventMouseMove);
      Event.stopObserving(document, "touchend", this.eventMouseUp);


      Event.stopObserving(document, "mouseup", this.eventMouseUp);
      Event.stopObserving(document, "mousemove", this.eventMouseMove);
      Event.stopObserving(document, "keypress", this.eventKeypress);
    }
  },
```

In Draggable:

```
initialize:
...
    this.eventMouseDown = this.initDrag.bindAsEventListener(this);
    Event.observe(this.handle, "mousedown", this.eventMouseDown);
      Event.observe(this.handle, "touchstart", this.eventMouseDown);


    Draggables.register(this);
  },


  destroy: function() {
    Event.stopObserving(this.handle, "mousedown", this.eventMouseDown);
    Event.stopObserving(this.handle, "touchstart", this.eventMouseDown);
    Draggables.unregister(this);
  },

...

initDrag: function(event) {
    if(!Object.isUndefined(Draggable._dragging[this.element]) &&
      Draggable._dragging[this.element]) return;
    if(Event.isLeftClick(event) || event.type == "touchstart") {
```

Along with editing prototype.js:

```
function pointerX(event) {
    var docElement = document.documentElement,
     body = document.body || { scrollLeft: 0 };


    if (event.changedTouches) return (event.changedTouches[0].clientX +
      (docElement.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft) -
      (docElement.clientLeft || 0));


    return event.pageX || (event.clientX +
      (docElement.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft) -
      (docElement.clientLeft || 0));
  }


  function pointerY(event) {
    var docElement = document.documentElement,
     body = document.body || { scrollTop: 0 };


    if (event.changedTouches) return (event.changedTouches[0].clientY +
      (docElement.scrollTop || body.scrollTop) -
      (docElement.clientTop || 0));


    return  event.pageY || (event.clientY +
       (docElement.scrollTop || body.scrollTop) -
       (docElement.clientTop || 0));
  }
```

Comment: that deserved an up vote.  sorry, but had to mention good use of just straight manipulating the methods, if you will, but wouldn't that be considered editing core functionality?  if you can help me decide, i might transition over to prototype on another app and that is the only place i could find someone talking about it.    Should work good ill give it a whirl and see how high i can push it up to central star.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to use parseInt function for X,Y coordinates, because I have some problem with Chrome browser on Android-it put something like 23.45435435345345345345345 to coordinates.

```
//Add parseInt ----------------[start]  
if (event.changedTouches) return (parseInt(event.changedTouches[0].clientY +
      (docElement.scrollTop || body.scrollTop) -
      (docElement.clientTop || 0),10));
//Add parseInt ----------------[end]
```