# On ipad how do you use draggable JQuery dom elements ( and circumvent the default window scrolling?)

Tags: jquery, ipad, draggable

I wrote a little web application where users create square blocks ( that are div elements) and then drag them around. It uses the JQuery UI library and the 'Draggable' effect.

The problem is that on an ipad the user can't drag these elements because when they put their finger on it to move it the element doesn't drag at all but the tablets entire 'browser window' does just as any other ipad page

So my question is how to circumvent this? Is there a way to 'lock' the window so the default works more like a desktop

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a jQuery UI 'draggable()' div draggable for touchscreen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026915/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-ui-draggable-div-draggable-for-touchscreen)

Comment: That question recommends adding http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

I added Touch-Punch after jQuery and it translates click events to touch events.

You can get it from  https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch