# Make element draggable for touchscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, touchscreen

I made a game where you have to drag the right figures to each other. But it won't work for touchscreen (it only has to work for touchscreen). Can someone help me? I would appreciate if you write the code i need since i am a beginner at coding and i dind'd manage to let it work with articles.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".selectable").draggable({
                addClasses: false,
                snap: true,
                stack: ".destination",
                scroll: false
            });

            $(".destination").draggable({
                snapMode: "inner"
            });

            $(".destination").draggable("disable");

            $(".destination").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var selectedShape = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                    var dropZone = $(this).attr("id");
                    dropZone = dropZone.replace("inside", "");
                    if(selectedShape == dropZone)
                    {
                        $("#" + selectedShape).draggable("disable");
                        checkShapeStatus();
                    }
                  //Als je een fout maakt
                    else {
                        alert("Wrong choice!");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        function checkShapeStatus() {
            var counter = 0;
            $(".selectable").each(function () {
                var $thisId = $(this);
                var booleanValue = $thisId.draggable('option', 'disabled');
                if (booleanValue)
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
                else {
                }
                //Als je alles goed hebt
                if(counter == 4)
                {
                    win.play();
                }
            })
        }
```

```css
#square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 8%;
  z-index:1;
}

#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: 8%;
  z-index:2;
}

#triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid green;
  margin-top: 8%;
  z-index:3;
}

#pacman {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid yellow;
  border-left: 60px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 60px solid yellow;
  border-top-left-radius: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px;
  margin-top: 8%;
  z-index:4;
}

#squareinside {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

#circleinside {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

#triangle-upinside {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid gray;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

#pacmaninside {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid gray;
  border-left: 60px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 60px solid gray;
  border-top-left-radius: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

body {
  background-color:bisque;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#centerText {
 font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
 font-size:xx-large;
 style="width:100%;
 height:100%;
 z-index:0;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 2%;
}


.grid-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px 200px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px 200px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Shape Matching</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="centerText" style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index:0;" align="center">
      Match the Shapes!
  </div>

  <div class="grid-1">
  <div id="pacmaninside" class="destination"></div>
  <div id="triangle-upinside" class="destination"></div>
  <div id="circleinside" class="destination"></div>
  <div id="squareinside" class="destination"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-2">
  <div id="square" class="selectable"></div>
  <div id="circle" class="selectable"></div>
  <div id="triangle-up" class="selectable"></div>
  <div id="pacman" class="selectable"></div>
</div>

  <audio id="win" src="media/win.mp3"></audio>

</body>

</html>
```

So i want to make this game work for a touchscreen device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a jQuery UI 'draggable()' div draggable for touchscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026915/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-ui-draggable-div-draggable-for-touchscreen)

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks for the reaction! I Saw this article already but can't make it work.

Comment: @MoshFeu I am a beginner at coding and don't know much about it yet, Could you write the code for me?

Comment: Ad far as I understand, you just need to download the dcript from - https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/blob/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js and add it to your website. It's a simple task so it's better you will do it so you could learn.

Comment: @MoshFeu could you write the code for me? I can't make it work

Comment: Just add the script https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js. [Demo](https://jsbin.com/gakoxop/edit?html,js).